# Using a variable in a regular expression

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I am using some [`sub(), gsub()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) functions to replace content stored in a variable.

Say for example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {str="hello bee"; patt="llo"; gsub(patt,"XX",str); print str}'
heXX bee
```

This replaces in the string contained in `str` all occurrences of `llo` with `XX`. Nice.

Now say that I want to use a more complex regular expression that uses both a variable and a pattern. For example, `"he"` + variable `patt`. How can I do it?

If I try with `gsub(/he/patt, ...)` it doesn't work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {str="hello bee"; patt="llo"; gsub(/he/patt,"XX",str); print str}'
```

Returns

```
hello bee
```

Instead of

```
XX bee
```

Comment: Added the [gawk] tag since it is the one I am using. Any solution using another distribution is also more than welcome : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's when you need string concatenation and so have to use string delimiters instead of regexp delimiters for the regexp:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {str="hello bee"; patt="llo"; gsub("he"patt,"XX",str); print str}'
XX bee
```

Just be aware that you'll then need to double up any escape chars since awk has to convert the string to a regexp first and so that will use up one of the escape chars.

Comment: Nice! So for example I need to say `gsub("he"patt"\\s","XX",str)`, that is, use `\\s` instead of `\s` to match the space.

Comment: Correct. If you use a single escape, `\s`, then gawk will give you a warning about the `\s` being treated as a literal `s` and then do so but some other awks won't warn you and IIRC some will interpret it as if you wrote `\\s` while others will treat it as `s`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {str="hello bee"; patt="llo"; gsub("he" patt,"XX",str); print str}'
XX bee
```

`/he/patt` doesn't concat the string together but `"he" patt` does.

Comment: Oh, nice! So there is no way to concat a string using `/he/`?

Comment: @fedorui `/he/` is not a string, its a regexp. There is no such thing as regexp concatenation, only string concatenation and conversion of strings to regexps when strings are used in a regexp context.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
awk 'BEGIN {str="hello bee"; patt="llo"; gsub(patt,"XX",str); print str}'
heXX bee
```

essentially you have to define the full pattern as a variable, not part of it.

Comment: Yep! This is a way, and thanks for it. Note, though, that I am wondering if there is a way to do such concatenation.